# Deserialize JSON with Camel Routes

Tags: java, json, jackson, apache-camel, quarkus

I'm trying to unmarshal json data generated by debezium inside a kafka topic.

My approach is simple, use POJOs and Jackson Library, however, since this json has a root object (initialized inside "{}") it throws an error.

This is the json received, I'm just interested on the payload:

```json
{
    "schema": {
        "type": "struct",
        "fields": [{
            "type": "double",
            "optional": false,
            "field": "codid"
        }, {
            "type": "string",
            "optional": true,
            "field": "__op"
        }, {
            "type": "string",
            "optional": true,
            "field": "__deleted"
        }],
        "optional": false,
        "name": "demo.RESCUE.Value"
    },
    "payload": {
        "codid": 0.0,
        "__op": "r",
        "__deleted": "false"
    }
}
```

And this is my Route:

```java
public class Routes extends RouteBuilder{

    public static class MySplitter {
        public List<Payload> splitBody(Rescue data) {
            return data.getPayload().stream().collect(toList());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {

        from("kafka:{{kafka.source.topic.name}}?brokers={{kafka.bootstrap.address}}&autoOffsetReset=earliest")
        .log("Received body: ${body}")
            .unmarshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson, Rescue.class)
            .split().method(MySplitter.class, "splitBody")
            .marshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson)
            .convertBodyTo(String.class)
            .log("Output: ${body}");
    }
    
}
```

And the error received:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.util.ArrayList<org.demo.pojos.rescue.Payload>` from Object value (token `JsonToken.START_OBJECT`)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just interested in `payload`, you have to extract this object from the whole JSON. For example with [JSONPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath).

Camel supports [JSONPath as expression language](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.14.x/languages/jsonpath-language.html). Therefore you can try something like

```
.log("Received body: ${body}")  // logs the full JSON
.setBody().jsonpathWriteAsString("$.payload")
.log("Reduced body: ${body}")   // should log the new body (only the payload)
...
```

Notice that you need to add the camel-jsonpath dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-jsonpath</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

or if you use SpringBoot

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-jsonpath-starter</artifactId>
</dependency>
```